# VS 2010 Win 7 Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have an issue that I haven't been able to fix.  When I open up a XAML file in VS 2010 Ultimate, my Win 7 changes to the Basic color scheme.  It's annoying and just started about a week ago.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks,

Tim Savage
ACEP, LLC

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a VS 2010 bug. You'd better get help here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

[Visual Studio 2010 Switches to Basic Color Scheme](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567407/visual-studio-2010-switches-to-basic-color-scheme) (there's a solution in the last comment)

Hope it solves your problem too.